# Dropdown's ul and li width isn't being displayed properly

Tags: html, css

I'm making a dropdown menu but for some reason the dropdown's width doesn't work.

I tried making a fiddle but I couldn't get it to work with the angular part.

I'm using angular so this is my HTML:

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in mainMenu" data-ng-switch on="item">{{item}}
        <ul data-ng-switch-when="Mina sidor">
            <li data-ng-repeat="subitem in subMenu.myPages">{{subitem}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS (I'm using SASS so it's a bit awkwardly formatted, I apologize for that) :

```
body, #main-menu, #main-menu li ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }

body {
    width: 100%; }

#main-menu {
    list-style: none; }

  #main-menu li:nth-child(even) {
    background: red; }

  #main-menu li {
    width: 12.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center; }

    #main-menu li ul {
      display: none;
      width: inherit; }

      #main-menu li ul li {
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        width: inherit;
        height: 30px;
        background: pink;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0; }

  #main-menu li:nth-child(4) {
    position: relative; }

    #main-menu li:nth-child(4):hover ul {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      background: yellow; }
```

Here's what the problem looks like:

[image: dropdown menu problem]

The ul dropdown and it's li:s width doesn't work for some reason, even though the box model in the console says that their width is in fact 12.5%. Why aren't they stretching to this width?

**Edit**: I had set the dropdown ul's width to 12.5% instead of 100%, it works perfect now.

Comment: You have the <li> width set to 12.5% of the parent which is the original <li>, i believe you should make it 100% to take the while width of the parent li

Comment: Oh right... changed the width of the <ul> to 100% and then it worked, thanks.